# Why isn't psql requiring me to enter a password to access psql for a login role I just created a password for?

Tags: postgresql, authentication, passwords

Just created a login role and subsequently, a database owned by a login role (both with the same name ". I specified a password. Typed `psql fplanner` and immediately was brought to a console without it having asked from a password. I'm logged into my computer's admin account, so maybe thats it.

Just wondering why it didn't ask me for a password, and when it would (or should), and also possibly how I might force it to prompt for a password every time before being accessed

- just created a rails app, and it is also not requiring login information to access the database. Could again be based off the fact that I'm root already I'm not sure

System: OSX El Capitan, PostgreSQL 9.4.4, PgAdmin 1.20.0

Extremely basic question here, but it doesn't appear to have been asked, so I decided to give it a go.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It probably didn't ask because it is set to "trust" (hopefully only for local connections).

While you are in psql and connected to the database run `SHOW hba_file;` to find out where your pg_hba.conf file is located. Open this file in your favorite text editor. It contains a quite a lot of comments thoroughtly explaning what you can do (lines starting with a # are comments).

In most default installs there are only two actual configuration lines:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Yours I expect to end in `trust` change them to `md5` for normal password based access.

Comment: I realize this was a while ago but I figured I'd give it a shot. I installed postgres with homebrew and my pg_hbs.conf file has all of its methods to trust. I don't mind being able to connect via my command line without a password, but it bothers me that I can connect from an app without a password. If I switch the methods for IPv4 and IPv6 to md5 would this require a password for both the command line and from an application? I'm wary to deploy without a password needed when setting up a connection with Pool.

Comment: @Nunchuk, yes then the commandline will require a password to there is nothing special about psql. Anything it does can be done by any app be sending the right commands over the connection.

Comment: @Eeike I see. Right on, thanks for replying. I appreciate it. I'll go ahead and switch them to md5.