# Requiring password for logging into postgres db

Tags: postgresql, authentication

I'm trying to require all user to provide their password to access my postgres db.

Currently, if I run `psql -U <username> <dbname>` or `psql --username=<username> <dbname>` I can log in without the password being provided.

I've followed along several stackoverflow questions and answers, and none have fixed this issue.

1. [Why isn't psql requiring me to enter a password to access psql for a login role I just created a password for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38424102/why-isnt-psql-requiring-me-to-enter-a-password-to-access-psql-for-a-login-role)
2. [How to Force Postgresql User Login with Password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29679507/how-to-force-postgresql-user-login-with-password)

Here is what my `pg_hba.conf`:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5  
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5  
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Comment: The fix is in what you do in `pg_hba.conf` and you have not shown that. Add its contents as text to your question. Also remember when you make changes to `pg_hba.conf` you need to `reload` the server.

Comment: Updated with the changes I made to my `pg_hba.conf`

Comment: I confirmed that it does work after the server reload